# Jquery on click function add class to a specific div

Tags: jquery

I have the code html

```
<div class="mobile"></div>
    <ul id="nav">
        <li><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="about.php">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="work.php">Work</a></li>
        <li><a href="contact.php">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

I need to:
On click add class to the ul

```
<div class="mobile"></div>
    <ul id="nav" class="visible">
        <li><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="about.php">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="work.php">Work</a></li>
        <li><a href="contact.php">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

I've tried:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('.mobile').click(function(){
        jQuery('#nav').removeClass('selected')
        jQuery('#nav').addClass('selected');
    });
});
```

When I click the first time the js add the class selected as I want;
but when I click again it does nothing, it should remove that class, but it doesn't work.
How can I do this?

Does anyone know the answer to this?

Comment: Just a note: `jQuery('#nav').removeClass('selected')` is missing a `;` in the end of the line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `toggleClass()`:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('.mobile').click(function(){
         jQuery('#nav').toggleClass('selected');
    });
});
```

Although its not clear to me you want `visible` class or `selected` class.

Answer (score 1):

What you do in your code is that everytime you click you remove and add the class. Hence it stays added after the first click. You can do this to get the desired behaviour:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.mobile').click(function(){
        $('#nav').toggleClass('selected');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

What do you want actually.
If you want to add the class, on clicking for more than one time, the class gets adding.
If you want to add if the class is not added and remove if the class is already added for the each click then the below code should work.

```
$('.mobile').click(function() {
   $('#nav').toggleClass('selected');
});
```